# Capture full canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am looking for a way to capture the complete canvas (including elements that are moved outside the canvas) to an image. I am using the KineticJS library and I am aware of the `toDataURL` function. The problem is that the image is clipped to the canvas bounds.

As a workaround I thought to copy all elements on the canvas to a temporary hidden canvas which is big enough to fit all elements and then use the `toDataURL` function. I was wondering if there is a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. I like the temporary canvas idea. Also, you could just resize the main canvas, apply an offsetting translation to all child elements, capture the image, then reverse-translate and resize back. This wouldn't be any more complex than copying to a hidden canvas. Plus, the single canvas approach would be more memory efficient.

Just my 3 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Alvin, you could just resize the canvas, here's how:

```
 stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);  // inner width of your window
 stage.setHeight(window.innerHeight); // inner height of your window
 stage.draw();    //redraw
```

This would resize your stage to the width and height of your window, but this would not account for the possibility that elements would be farther than your window, but you can just modify the number inside the .set functions to account for the farthest right/left one.

If you were looking for a quick way to copy all elements in your canvas to another stage you could serialize it:

```
  var json = stage.toJSON();
  var newStage = Kinetic.Node.create(stageJson, 'newContainer');
```